# Dart mailer don't send mail

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I was use mailer 0.8.1 and try create demo app to send mail in dartlang but it don't work.
This my code:

```dart
  var options = new GmailSmtpOptions()
    ..username = 'my gmail account'
    ..password = 'my gmail pass'; 
  var emailTransport = new SmtpTransport(options);

  var envelope = new Envelope()
    ..from = 'testmailer@gmail.com'
    ..recipients.add('testmailer@gmail.com')
    ..subject = 'Testing mailer'    
    ..text = 'This is test mailer'
    ..html = '<h1>Test send mail</p>';

    .then((success) => print('Email sent! $success'))
    .catchError((e) => print('Error occured: $e'));
```

but when i run app it don't print anything.
Somebody can help me?
thanks1

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this package yet but it looks you are missing some `send` call that would on success lead to `.then()`/`.catchError()`

Answer (score 0):

The envelope can not send the mail itself you have to use the SmtpTransport for that:

```dart
  emailTransport.send(envelope)
      .then((_) => print('Email sent!)))
      .catchError((e) => print('Error occurred: $e'));
```